# Yii2 GridView pagination with only next and prev links and no TotalCount

Tags: php, gridview, pagination, yii2

There is a huge DB table with millions of rows and it needs to be outputed in a GridView with only prev and next links in the paginator.

I don't want to use 'select count(*)' on such tables, so there's no TotalCount. Also I want to prevent users from setting huge offset and degrade MySQL performance.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: **Accepted answer has an error:** There should be
$page = $pagination->getPage(true);
instead of $page = $pagination->getPage(true) + 1; Otherwise you always skip first page of the results because generated query contains "offset 20" for $page == 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've waited several days to make sure I wasn't missing some obvious solution, but now need to hardcode it on my own. The quickest way I've found is to extend DataProvider and rewrite methods: `prepareTotalCount()`, `prepareModels()`:

```
namespace common;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\base\InvalidConfigException;
use yii\db\QueryInterface;

class BigActiveDataProvider extends ActiveDataProvider
{
    protected function prepareTotalCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    protected function prepareModels()
    {
        if (!$this->query instanceof QueryInterface) {
            throw new InvalidConfigException('The "query" property must be an instance of a class that implements the QueryInterface e.g. yii\db\Query or its subclasses.');
        }
        $query = clone $this->query;

        if (($pagination = $this->getPagination()) !== false) {
            $pagination->validatePage = false;
            $page = $pagination->getPage(true) + 1;
            $offset = $page*$pagination->getPageSize();

            $query->limit($pagination->getLimit() + 1)->offset($offset);
        }
        if (($sort = $this->getSort()) !== false) {
            $query->addOrderBy($sort->getOrders());
        }

        $res = $query->all($this->db);

        if (($pagination = $this->getPagination()) !== false) {
            $pagination->totalCount = ($page)*$pagination->getPageSize();
            if (count($res) > $pagination->getPageSize()) {
                unset($res[count($res)-1]);
                $pagination->totalCount++;
            }
        }

        return $res;
    }
}
```

I don't think that this is the best solution, but it works as planned and it doesn't limit `ActiveDataProvider` capabilities. It only makes sure that count(*) query won't be executed and there is no need to set `totalCount`.

Comment: This is a good answer but not perfect, as it actually shows the second page as the first (IE it sets the offset to 11).  To fix this you need to not set the page to + 1 at the top, so like this               $query->limit($pagination->getLimit() + 1)->offset($offset);
 and towards the bottom you do need to set the page + 1                $pagination->totalCount = ($page + 1)*$pagination->getPageSize();

Answer (score 1):

When you create your dataprovider, make sure to specify the totalCount to a number, such as 0, which will prevent Yii from running a count(*) query.

You should then create a replacement class for yii\widgets\Linkpager that generates only the links you want to appear.

Finally, attach your pager to your GridView.

```
<?php GridView::widget([
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'pager' => [
   'class' => 'path\to\my\custom\Pager\'
 ]
 'columns' => 
         ....
]; ?>
```